# Regex Word Boundary including hyphen

Tags: regex

With the regular expression `\s{2}\b` I'm trying to replace the last two **whitespaces** before a word with a pipe `(|)` using a Word Boundary, but it's ignoring the number `-18.055,81`. With what kind of expression I can also get the last two **whitespaces** before `-18.055,81`?

Example:

```js
1234 - This is a test        18.055,81        -18.055,81        0,00        0,00        18.055,81
```

Results in:

```js
1234 - This is a test       |18.055,81        -18.055,81       |0,00       |0,00       |18.055,81
```

What I want:

```js
1234 - This is a test       |18.055,81       |-18.055,81       |0,00       |0,00       |18.055,81
```

Comment: If Lookaheads are supported, you may use `\s{2}(?=\S)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
\s{2}(?=-?\d)
\s{2}(?=-?\w)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wzMQdL/1). Details:

- `\s{2}` - two whitespace chars
- `(?=-?\d)` - that are immediately followed with an optional hyphen and then a digit.

If there are any other word chars expected (letters, or underscores), replace `\d` with `\w`.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for :-)